# Staying inner link in a div with event and prevendDefault

Tags: html, jquery

I've html

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between" id="openclose">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
            <a href="theurl" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
$('#openclose').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ///here open close commmand
});
```

How to avoid the prevent default and openclose events commands on the inner link?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want that if i click outside link, then occurs open or close. If i click on the link then url's website opens.

Comment: Why do you have the `e.preventDefault();`?  Seems you can just remove that and it does what you want.

Comment: Alternatively, add `e..stopPropagation()` on your `<a>` so that it doesn't hit the #openclose handler